# Why can't I import AbstactUser from django.contrib.auth.models?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on an API to communicate a server with mobile devices using Django REST framework and I created a custom user model per the docs, which works great when using `python manage.py runserver` normally.  When I run `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.80` to make a couple preliminary test calls django complains with `ImportError: cannot import name AbstractUser`.  I import this in line 8 of my models like `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`. I've tried different ways of importing the class but Django says it isn't there, and I can't find anything from Google that resembles this error.  Has anyone seen this or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What version of Django are you using? The abstract user stuff is new in 1.5+.

Comment: One reason was the typo. `0.0.0.0.80` is supposed to be `0.0.0.0:80`. Still doesn't work on port 80 because of the sudo but it works on 8000. Not a complete answer.....yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that when you use `sudo` you are discarding your environment variables, including for instance your `PYTHONPATH`.  Try `sudo -E` to preserve your environment and see if that works.

But, in general, I'd advise against trying to run your app in-place with `sudo`.  Among other reasons, it may create temporary files, .pyc files, etc. with the wrong permissions.  Maybe make a copy of your app and set it up properly with gunicorn etc.?

Comment: That sounds like good advice, and I will likely follow it. This particularly didn't work but I'm thinking that has something to do with the virtualenv I'm using. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I accepted this answer because Andrew is correct in the `sudo` discards whatever environment is currently running although the `sudo -E` didn't work.  The problem was the typo I mentioned in my comment on the original post.  Thanks for the help!